# Sort a Map of Lists by a List of Values

Tags: java, list, sorting

The scenario is I have the following Map:

```
[
  a:[4,2,6,9,-1],
  b:[2,6],
  c:[1],
  d:[9,9,9,4]
]
```

and the following list of values:

```
[2,4,1]
```

and I wish to sort the map keys by the first occurrence of a value in the sorting list:

```
result: [a,b,d,c] (because both a&b have a 2, d has a 4, and c has a 1)
```

Currently I have the following but it is at O(n^3). Is there a more efficient way of doing this sort?

```
private static List<String> orderByList(Map<String, List<Integer>> numByString, List<String> sortingList) {
    Map<String, List<String>> stringsByTags = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (String string : numByString.keySet()) {
        for (Integer num : numByString.get(string)) {
            boolean foundTag = false;
            // go through all elements until you find one that is is the sortingList
            // add it to the stringsByTags
            for (String tag : sortingList) {
                if (string.equals(tag)) {
                    if (stringsByTags.containsKey(tag)) {
                        stringsByTags.get(tag).add(string);
                    } else {
                        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        newList.add(string);
                        stringsByTags.put(tag, newList);
                    }
                    foundTag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (foundTag) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //combine the stringsByTags
    List<String> ordered = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String tag : sortingList) {
        if (stringsByTags.containsKey(tag)) {
            ordered.addAll(stringsByTags.get(tag));
        }
    }
    return ordered;
}
```

Comment: These kind of questions should be on code review and not here.

Comment: From the expected result,and method signature, it seems you wish to sort the map *keys*, not values. I'm not sure I agree this belongs to code review, he is asking if there is a better algorithm, not for remarks on the style/reusability/testability/etc that pertain to a code review.

Comment: Correct Hugues. Will update that.

Comment: what about an map entry which has none of the values? e.g. `e:[8,7,6]`. where will it be inserted then? simply unordered at the end?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer In my situation they won't be added, but for other users of this problem I'd agree with adding them unsorted at the end.

Comment: Should the result be a map with the keys sorted according to the algorithm? or do you just want a list of the keys?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**. Calculate the score of each Entry in your map

```
    values = [2,4,1];
    Integer score = 0;
    for(int i=0;i < a.size();i++) {
        if(values.binarySearch(a[i])) {
            score ++;
        }
    }
```

The running time is *O(a.size()*log(values.size))*. The total cost to calculate the score of the whole map is O(map.size * entry.size * log(values.size)). In a simple way, it will be *O(knlog(m))*.

**Step 2**. Sort the `ScoreObj` array. The cost will be *O(klog(k))* where k refers to map's size.

```
class ScoreObj {
        Integer score;
        String key;
    }
```

Override the compare function of `ScoreObj` so the `ScoreObj` will be sorted by it's `score`.

It's slightly better than *O(n^3)*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your algorithm sorts map entries by the index of the first value that is found in the sorting list. Let's call this index `sortingIndex`.

One way to do this is to first create a `Map<String, Integer>`, where the keys remain the same and the value is the `sortingIndex`:

```
Map<String, Integer> sortingMap = new HashMap<>();

numByString.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<>(v);
        int sortingIndex = IntStream.range(0, sortingList.size())
            .filter(i -> values.contains(sortingList.get(i)))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        sortingMap.put(k, sortingIndex);
    });
```

Now, simply order the `sortingMap` by values and get the keys:

```
List<String> orderedKeys = sortingMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 approaches which both should have a smaller O than yours. My first approach should have a smaller O than my second one, because it also removes map entries after processing them. My test data looks like this. I chose `LinkedHashMap` because it keeps insertion order, which is important in this case:

```
Map<String, List<String>> p = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
p.put("a", Arrays.asList("4", "2", "6", "9", "-1"));
p.put("b", Arrays.asList("2", "6"));
p.put("c", Arrays.asList("1"));
p.put("d", Arrays.asList("9", "9", "9", "4"));
p.put("e", Arrays.asList("8", "7", "6"));
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("2", "4", "1"));
Map<String, List<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>();
```

now my first approach which removes entries after sorting them:

```
for (String s : values) {
    for (Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> it = p.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<String, List<String>> x = it.next();
        if (x.getValue().contains(s)) {
            if (!result.containsKey(x.getKey())) {
                result.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue());
                sorted.add(x.getKey());
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach looks a bit simpler to understand but works just as well:

```
for (String s : values) {
    for (String st : p.keySet()) {
        if (p.get(st).contains(s)) {
            if (!result.containsKey(st)) {
                result.put(st, p.get(st));
                sorted.add(st);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if I print the list as well as the map, my output is this in both cases:

```
[a, b, d, c]
[a, b, d, c]
```